# GET RESPONSE returns SW 6400

Tags: smartcard, apdu

I created a DF File and some sons EF and sons DF under it. Then I SELECT the file and perform GET RESPONSE command. I am expecting data from the get response command but instead I receive 6400. 6400 is 'No Diagnosis'

I have no idea what might cause this error.

Comment: GET RESPONSE is applicable for T=0 protocol mostly. Are you sure, that you need it? What is the ATR of your card?

Comment: Product is T=0, ATR is 3B79980000F704010000800104A9

Answer (score 0):

You can try select file command after select MF and after that select DF and so on which level you want to select.
It could be bug in card OS also.
It will be more clear if you can share full APDU traces and card type.

Comment: I am selecting level 2 DF

Comment: 00A40000023F00 SW 9000
00200000 08 <DEF KEY> SW 9000
00A40000 02 1000 SW 9000
00C00000 1C SW 6400

I am actually using a IFX card and has a specific product manual
Manual is based on standards also. Difference only on the specific file for the product.
I was also thinking of the OS bug. but how can I be sure?

Comment: Get response command is not required here. Because If SW1 is set to '61', then the process is completed and before issuing any other command, a GET RESPONSE
command may be issued with the same CLA and using SW2.